# PrimeFaces DataTable with custom LazyDataModel does not work with commandButton inside columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, commandbutton

I have a datatable with a LazyDataModel that works fine with paging. However I put buttons in a column and they do not fire.
If I remove the lazy mode these buttons work fine.
The truth is I tried everything and just removing the lazy mode works.

```
        <p:dataTable 
            id="basicDT" 
            var="user" 
            lazy="true"
            value="#{userMB.userLazyDataModel}" 
            selectionMode="single"
            rowKey="#{user.id}" 
            selection="#{userMB.selectedUser}" 
            rows="10"
            paginatorPosition="bottom" 
            paginator="true" 
            paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" 
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage}:{totalPages} / ({totalRecords})"
            >


            <f:facet name="header">#{msgs['userList.title']}</f:facet>

             <p:ajax  event="rowDblselect" listener="#{userMB.onRowSelect}" />
            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:36px;text-align:center"/>
            <p:column width="35">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${user.isAccountLocked()}}">
                        <span class="fa fa-fw fa-lock" ></span>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <span class="fa fa-fw fa-unlock" ></span>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:50px">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">#{msgs['user.document']}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.document}"  />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">#{msgs['user.username']}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.username}"  />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">#{msgs['user.firstName']}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName}"  />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">#{msgs['user.lastName']}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}"  />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">#{msgs['user.email']}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.email}"  />
            </p:column>

            <p:column >
                <f:facet name="header">#{msgs['user.phoneNumber']}</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.phoneNumber}" />
            </p:column>


            <p:column style="text-align: center" width="140" >
                <h:commandButton value="submit"  action="#{userMB.test}" update="@all">  
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{user}" target="#{userMB.selectedUser}" /> 
                </h:commandButton>  
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primefaces DataTable, lazy loading and CommandButton per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918834/primefaces-datatable-lazy-loading-and-commandbutton-per-row)